# Android: Gallery with different views and interactive elements

Tags: android, android-activity, gallery, element, interactive

Imagine a Gallery widget with three elements:

- 0 - with TextView, ImageView
- 1 - with TextView only
- 2 - with interactive UI elements: Button, EditText

I'm trying to figure out how to resolve the problem with Gallery widget. Gallery has elements with different views, and the third element has an interactive UI elements (button, text fields).

Whether to use Gallery widget (with elements in circle) or different activities and transitions between? If activities is answer, how to repeat the activities in cycles with horizontal touch movement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tried customAdapter ???
I mean i m not seeing any prob. in it, as u can use different layout for different child's in getView , N for clickable view put your clicklistner within adapter itself ......
try it ...... i wl put code snippet if prob. persist

Comment: Thanks! I will try to implement by your advice. Anyway, it will be very useful to have your code here, because each Gallery widget example on internet is related with showing images or string array in Gallery widget.